# Crontab have permission issues on file of its owner? Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have a very simple cron job written in shell script, which scp a file from another server to local.
e.g,

```
#!/bin/bash
scp $REMOTE:/$FILE ./
```

Of course, the server need a private key to login, which I have config file saving HostName, IdentityFile in (~/.ssh/id_rsa, a mod with 600).

However, it has "permission denied" issue when the cron running....

```
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/xxx>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=xxxx>
Message-Id: <20120118235702.33A7B16C03B5@xxx-xxxx-deskbox>
Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2012 18:57:02 -0500 (EST)

Permission denied (publickey).
```

I checked everywhere, it says the crontab will be running as the owner/user's environment.

Anyone have a solution for this?
Thanks!

Comment: This is not a Cron error, it is an SSH error.  See http://serverfault.com/questions/39733/why-do-i-get-permission-denied-publickey-when-trying-to-ssh-from-local-ubunt

Comment: The server won't accept your key. Check that you can log in manually. You can add key to command line `scp -i ~/.my_key_somewhere ...`

Comment: Thanks jkj. Yes, manually run the script is a success. I test it before I put in the crontab, thought it will be same.... I tried with -i in my script: `scp -i /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa xxxx@$REMOTE:$FILE $FOLDER/ `        still no luck. Denied.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. There was a passphrase on my id_rsa key. 
Hence manually running won't require it as the phrase is in the session; 
while crontab need the passphrase. 
Delete the passphrase

```
ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase]
```

and enter empty for new passphrase; or check [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112396/how-do-i-remove-the-passphrase-for-the-ssh-key-without-having-to-create-a-new-ke)

Hope my answer can help some programmers several hours of debugging..