# How do I create a user and add an SSH key on an EC2 instance?

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, sudo, ssh-keys

I can `ssh` into a remote EC2 instance with `ec2-user` and the keypair in the EC2 account with root(sudo) privileges.

How can I manually create another non-ec2-user user account, add an SSH key, and add `sudo` permissions to that user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create the user account**

First, create the user account using the standard Linux/UNIX `useradd` command:

```
NEWUSER='newusername'
SSHPUBKEY='ssh-ed25519 AAAA..xyz jamieson@desktop'
sudo useradd -m $NEWUSER
```

**Add the SSH public key to that user's authorized_keys file**

It's critical to chown the directory back to the user, or the SSH daemon will reject the file that's owned by `root` and not `$NEWUSER`. (Another way to do this is to use `ssh-copy-id`, but this way can be done in the same login session.)

```
sudo mkdir /home/$NEWUSER/.ssh/
echo "$SSHPUBKEY" | sudo tee -a /home/$NEWUSER/.ssh/authorized_keys >/dev/null
sudo chown -R $NEWUSER:$NEWUSER /home/$NEWUSER/.ssh
```

**Set up sudo permissions for that user**

This uses the standard /etc/sudoers.d directory (found in all major distributions) to add sudo permissions with an "ALL" role to the user account.

`echo "$NEWUSER   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | sudo tee "/etc/sudoers.d/$NEWUSER" >/dev/null`

(Disclaimer: I wrote the first release of a [tool](https://github.com/userify/shim/blob/master/shim.py#L227) that automates this at [Userify](https://userify.com).)

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/a/218995/133137 for some information on why `chown` is needed. Fortunately, just creating the file like this and then `chown`ing it is sufficient.