# AWS SFTP connection closed error

Tags: amazon-web-services, sftp

WHen I try to connect with my server endpoint getting connection closed. It should be connected with server endpoint.

[image: Sccreeshot]

[AWS Connection Closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJUsP.png)

Comment: Where practical please copy and paste the error message as text rather than linking to a screenshot - it makes it easier for people to help you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/39733/why-do-i-get-permission-denied-publickey-when-trying-to-ssh-from-local-ubunt/39735, so check the answers there see if any of them help.  Is your username the same on both machines?  Show your command, not just the error (and paste text not screenshots please.)

Comment: And welcome to ServerFault!  It's the perfect place to find answers for this type of question. In the future, try googling for the error message in quotes, like this: `"permission denied (publickey)"`.  Chances are good you'll find your question already answered.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is asking for the public key as authentication, You need to make sure that the public key of the server where you are accessing from is on the authorized_keys file of your endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs for details, selinux may restrict, make sure the "test" user has appropriate privilege.

Ref: https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/limiting-access-with-sftp-jails-on-debian-and-ubuntu/